# Using Google's Java authentication within Scala?

Tags: scala, google-authentication

I'm currently attempting to build a GPlay authentication service on a Scala backend. The client is sending through their ID Token and salt; and from here, I'm attempting to use [Google's Backend Auth documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) in order to authenticate the user's GPlay account.

As expected, Google's Java libs can all be used without issue with Scala.

Java/Scala imports:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;
```

Java:

```
GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
    .build();
```

Scala:

```
val verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
  .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
  .build();
```

Their guide seems to be leaving a lot out - namely, what should be instantiated for the transport, jsonFactory, and CLIENT_ID vars. It also does not make any reference as to why the CLIENT_ID should be stored in a singletonList, rather than just a string as we would normally implement on the client.

Currently, I'm getting (as expected), "cannot resolve symbol" errors for transport, jsonFactory, and CLIENT_ID. I've the same error appearing for Collections, but I assume that's because I haven't attempted to create any collection - as no indication is given on the documentation as to what we should be looking to instantiate a collection with.

Any help that could be offered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the below code from here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Plus plus = new Plus.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
    .setApplicationName("Google-PlusSample/1.0")
    .build();
```

There you can see an example on how to create the transport and jsonFactory variables you need.

I already created a token validation functionality on Java, In case you need it below is an example:

```
public static Optional<GoogleIdToken> validateGoogleToken(final String idTokenString) {
        try {
            Optional<String> clientIDConfValueOptional = PlayUtil.getConfValue("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID");
            if (clientIDConfValueOptional.isPresent()) {

                //PLEASE NOTE!!!!
                //for ANDROID with PlayServices 8.3 + issuer=https://accounts.google.com
                //OTHERWISE issuer=accounts.google.com
                //the otherwise is without "https://"
                GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(
                       MiscUtil.NET_HTTP_TRANSPORT, JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                        .setAudience(Arrays.asList(clientIDConfValueOptional.get()))
                        // If you retrieved the token on Android using the Play Services 8.3 API 
                        //                        or newer, set
                        // the issuer to "https://accounts.google.com". Otherwise, set the issuer to
                        // "accounts.google.com". If you need to verify tokens from multiple sources, build
                        // a GoogleIdTokenVerifier for each issuer and try them both.
                        .setIssuer("accounts.google.com")
                        .build();

                GoogleIdToken googleIdToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
                if (googleIdToken != null) {
                    Payload payload = googleIdToken.getPayload();

                    // Print user identifier
                    String userId = payload.getSubject();
//                    System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

                    // Get profile information from payload
//                    String email = payload.getEmail();
//                    System.out.println("email = " + email);
//                    boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
//                    System.out.println("emailVerified = " + emailVerified);
//                    String name = (String) payload.get("name");
//                    System.out.println("name = " + name);
//                    String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
//                    System.out.println("pictureUrl = " + pictureUrl);
//                    String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
//                    System.out.println("locale = " + locale);
//                    String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
//                    System.out.println("familyName = " + familyName);
//                    String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
//                    System.out.println("givenName = " + givenName);

                    // Use or store profile information
                    // ...
                    return Optional.ofNullable(googleIdToken);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("CLIENT_ID key can't be found on application.conf file");
            }
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.error("Error: ", ex);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

You probably know how to translate this code from Java to Scala anyway if you need some help you can use a service like this: [java to scala converter](http://javatoscala.com/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that's an in-depth answer. Thank you! The only issue I'm having now is that Scala seems to be having issues with accessing the Java constructor for the Builder object - throwing back "cannot resolve constructor GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder". Any ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: Maybe we're using different google-api-client version, on my code I'm using: 

libraryDependencies += "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.22.0". Which version are you using?

Comment: Nope, exact same. I can see the Java constructor just fine. Scala doesn't seem to want to recognise it.

Comment: Ok, maybe the problem is that we're using different arguments. In my code the MiscUtil.NET_HTTP_TRANSPORT variable has the value returned by this method: com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(); what is the value of the transport variable you're using?

Comment: Sorry, think I solved that by instantiating (and overriding) most of Google's JSONFactory stuff. So the last thing that's confusing me is the audience - I thought this was just where we passed in our Client Token ID? So why does it require a collection?

Comment: Don't know why it is a collection, the docs don't say anything. But yes you need to pass your google client id there. Just in case remember that the google client id is a string like this: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143805/discussion-between-pedrohidalgo-and-eoghan).